# What is the difference between a BJT's DC and AC gain and why are they different

Tags: bjt, small-signal

Could you please explain what is the difference between the DC and AC gain of a BJT and why is the gain different for DC and AC?  Where would the different gains be used?

Comment: There is sufficient clarity to be answered. Should not have been closed.

Comment: I also support the opinion that the closure is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, DC beta is the ratio of instantaneous collector and base currents i.e. \$I_C/I_B\$. AC beta is the ratio of changes in the currents i.e. \$di_C/di_B\$.

The former can be used for DC analysis (e.q. quiescent) whilst the latter can be used for AC analysis (e.g. small signal).

At different temperatures, these two can be different. Also, the frequency is a factor. The transition frequency, for example, or gain-bandwidth product, tells where the AC current gain is "lost" (i.e. unity gain) for a specific operating condition. BJT datasheets usually show graphs for this value for different collector currents.